# Вызов метода apply в Function без параметров

Tags: java

Пытаюсь вывести значение через метод-адаптер:

```
System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
```

Сам метод и класс:

```
private static Integer adapt(Function<C, Integer> func, C c) {
        return func.apply(c) / 25;
}

class C {
        public Integer getAge() {
            return 100;
        }
    }
```

В таком виде все работает, хотя метод getAge не принимает параметров, а Function требует параметры для apply. Если getAge сделать статическим, то компилятор уже выдаст ошибку, что ожидаемо. Почему в 1 случае не возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка при вызове метода `getAge` не возникает, так как функциональная сигнатура любого нестатического метода первым параметром принимает ссылку на объект, для которого вызывается метод. Ваш код `func.apply(c)` внутри JVM исполняется как `c.getAge`.

Статический метод без аргументов так вызывать нельзя - у него нет первого параметра, как у методов. Для статического метода без аргументов нужно использовать класс `Supplier`.

Вот короткий пример:

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static String staticMethod() {
        return "Hello World from a static method";
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Supplier<String> stringProvider = HelloWorld::staticMethod;
        System.out.println(stringProvider.get());

     }
}
```

У меня печатает `Hello World from a static method`

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Function  не причем. Проблема в обращении из статики к нестатике. Чтобы было понятнее, я приведу несколько примеров.

Пример №1

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
    }

    private static Integer adapt(Function<C, Integer> func, C c) {
        return func.apply(c) / 25;
    }

}

class C {
    public Integer getAge() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Здесь все работает.

Пример №2.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
    }

    private static Integer adapt(Function<C, Integer> func, C c) {
        return func.apply(c) / 25;
    }

    class C {
        public Integer getAge() {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Теперь у нас появилась проблема с вызовом getAge из статического метода, вместе с тем, вызов из метода start, являющийся нестатическим, по прежнему работает. Проблема в том, что теперь класс С является вложенным классом, т.е. частью класса Main, он не может быть вызван из статического контекста, следовательно, мы получаем проблему при попытке вызвать new C() из статического метода.

Пример №3

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(adapt(C::getAge, new C()));
    }

    private static Integer adapt(Function<C, Integer> func, C c) {
        return func.apply(c) / 25;
    }

    static class C {
        public Integer getAge() {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Теперь все снова работает. Вложенные классы могут быть статическими, как только класс С стал статическим, проблема вызова из статического метода исчезла.

Comment: Спасибо за розьяснение, но это не то. Здесь речь не о статических классах, а о статических методах. Вот если в последнем компильном примере метод getAge класса C сделать статическим, то получим ошибку. Почему?